# How to trace SOAP message on Glassfish 3

Tags: java, web-services, logging, glassfish, jax-ws

I would like to save to a server log SOAP envelopes for web service deployed on Glassfish version 3. I know that I can use Wireshark or similar net sniffing tool, but I would prefer to  have the messages stored in Glassfish log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all looks a bit confusing, but here's the documentation for traffic logging on Glassfish/Metro

https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/guide/Logging.html

Comment: To be more specyfic: the option from the mentioned docs needs to be added to domain.xml config file. For example to log everything we need to add

<jvm-options>-Dcom.sun.metro.soap.dump=true</jvm-options>